# Why is not uploaded in spring with ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to upload a file and want to save in /resources/images folder. Here is my controller:
RestController.java

```
@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/cont")
public class RestController {

      @RequestMapping(value = "/echofile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> echoFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

            MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile("file");
            Long size = multipartFile.getSize();
            String contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
            InputStream stream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);

            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("fileoriginalsize", size);
            map.put("contenttype", contentType);
            map.put("base64", new String(Base64Utils.encode(bytes)));

            return map;
        }
```

my index.jsp is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring MVC - Upload File</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var isJpg = function(name) {
    return name.match(/jpg$/i)
};

var isPng = function(name) {
    return name.match(/png$/i)
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var file = $('[name="file"]');
    var imgContainer = $('#imgContainer');

    $('#btnUpload').on('click', function() {
        var filename = $.trim(file.val());

        if (!(isJpg(filename) || isPng(filename))) {
            alert('Please browse a JPG/PNG file to upload ...');
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/SimpleAjaxJqueryPicUpload/api/echofile",
            type: "POST",
            data: document.getElementById("image"),
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
          }).done(function(data) {
              imgContainer.html('');
              var img = '<img src="data:' + data.contenttype + ';base64,'
                  + data.base64 + '"/>';

              imgContainer.append(img);
          }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
              //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
              alert('File upload failed ...');
          });

    });

    $('#btnClear').on('click', function() {
        imgContainer.html('');
        file.val('');
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<body style="font-family: calibri; font-size: 8pt">
<div>
<div id="fileForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="image"/>
    <button id="btnUpload" type="button">Upload file</button>
    <button id="btnClear" type="button">Clear</button>
</div>
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the file is not uploaded. When I clicked the button, it has shown upload failed alert. How can I solve it?

Comment: controller is ok. I have checked it..It's workd on 
`<form id="fileForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="image"/>
    <button id="btnUpload" type="button">Upload file</button>
    <button id="btnClear" type="button">Clear</button>
</div>
<div id="imgContainer"></div>
</form>`  but when I changed form to div,it didn't work.why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please include these lines:

```
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file', jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
 data: formData
```

Your AJAX code look like this -

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', jQuery('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'path',
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: formData, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        })
```